# Creating a Cluster using boto in AWS Reshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-redshift

```
obj = boto.redshift.layer1.RedshiftConnection()
obj.create_cluster(
    cluster_identifier='bototest',
    node_type='dw.hsl.xlarge',
    master_username='suresh',
    master_user_password='Suresh123',
    db_name='dev',
    cluster_type='single-node',
    cluster_security_groups='None',
    vpc_security_group_ids='None',
    cluster_subnet_group_name='None',
    availability_zone='us-east-1',
    preferred_maintenance_window='None',
    cluster_parameter_group_name='None',
    automated_snapshot_retention_period='None',
    port=5439,
    cluster_version='None',
    allow_version_upgrade='None',
    number_of_nodes=1,
    publicly_accessible='None',
    encrypted='None')
```

Why do I get this the error?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.13.3-py2.7.egg/boto/redshift/layer1.py", line 577, in create_cluster
    path='/', params=params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.13.3-py2.7.egg/boto/redshift/layer1.py", line 2189, in _make_request
    body=json_body)
**boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request**
{u'RequestId': u'76d9f16d-2994-11e3-85df-a5bac8eed36b', u'Error': {u'Message': u'boolean must follow xsd1.1 definition', u'Code': u'MalformedInput', u'Type': u'Sender'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters `allow_version_upgrade`, `publicly_accessible`, and `encrypted` expect `bool` values, either `True` or `False`.  You are passing a string containing the value None.  Also, for `cluster_version` you are also passing a string containing the value None rather than the special constant `None`.

The online docs for the `create_cluster` method are pretty complete.  You can find them here:  http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/redshift.html#boto.redshift.layer1.RedshiftConnection.create_cluster.